# Multiple linear regression takes into account more variables and adjusts the value of estimates and p-values, why then use linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

Note the difference in Wr.Hnd of multiple linear regression is nearly halved to that of linear regression. The same applies to SexMale (not shown).

Case in point: Multiple Linear Regression

```
survmult <- lm(Height~Wr.Hnd+Sex, data = surveyNA)
summary(survmult)



> summary(survmult)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Wr.Hnd + Sex, data = surveyNA)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-17.3693  -3.7119   0.5632   4.1670  19.4328 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 132.5445     6.0446  21.928  < 2e-16 ***
Wr.Hnd        1.8760     0.3406   5.509 1.36e-07 ***
SexMale       9.3164     1.3033   7.148 2.70e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.646 on 165 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5601,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5548 
F-statistic:   105 on 2 and 165 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Case in point: Linear Regression

```
survfit <- lm(Height~Wr.Hnd, data =surveyNA)
survfit
summary(survfit)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Wr.Hnd, data = surveyNA)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-19.8332  -4.8332  -0.4516   4.6714  24.5453 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 108.9530     5.7781   18.86   <2e-16 ***
Wr.Hnd        3.3785     0.3057   11.05   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.583 on 166 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4238,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4204 
F-statistic: 122.1 on 1 and 166 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The "Stratified Analysis"?

[image]

Comment: If you study height of a species with sexual dimorphism (such as humans), you must include sex in the model. That's usually the most important predictor after age. What is `Wr.Hnd`?

Comment: Wr.Hnd =  Writing Handspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, I see no reason to use simple linear regression instead of multiple linear regression. Sex is clearly an important variable. But see below.

However, in general, you sometimes have only one independent variable and, then, you use simple linear regression by definition. Other times, you investigate a model with several potential independent variables and find that only one is of any interest.

Finally, some people like stratified analysis. In your case, that would mean looking at men and women separately. Then you could have two simple linear regressions. This can be more intuitive for some people, particularly if there is an interaction between the two IVs.

Comment: With regard to your last paragraph, do you mean something like the graph that I just uploaded only that they are in separate graphs?

Comment: @Matthew The result from stratified regression would be very similar to the result from `lm(Height~Wr.Hnd*Sex, data = surveyNA)`, i.e., a regression model that includes the interaction.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Although it would look different because if you stratify it you could get different slopes. (As @Roland notes, if you add an interaction it will be more similar).